# jQuery fadeIn of text does not fade in smoothly

Tags: jquery, fadein

Unlike other posts I have seen here, I am using jQuery fadeIn for variable text and NOT for an image. I am seeing it fade in a little choppy with one final pulse into full color. I'd like it to fade in more gradually. I have posted it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sPFa/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong. What browser is this happening on? Also, if your system doesn't have enough memory available, it could cause performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for looking. Happening for me on Safari only.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a webkit rendering issue, a difference between a static element and something mid-animation (probably font-smoothing related). This "bug" can be <strike>fixed</strike> hacked around by applying an opacity to your text targeting webkit (because it's not an issue on firefox):

```
-webkit-opacity: .99;
```

and your animation will be smooth in chrome/safari: http://jsfiddle.net/davechiu/9sPFa/3/

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me.. Maybe try increasing the time Interval  from 1300 to 2500 and check if you see the same results..

```
// fade in of 3 phrases
        $("#fade1").fadeIn(2500, function() {
            $("#fade2").fadeIn(2500, function() {
                $("#fade3").fadeIn(2500);
            });
        });​
```

Comment: The time interval change did not make any difference. Thanks, though.